# Keyword "this" doesn't work in Listener

Tags: java, android, actionlistener, android-context

I call method, where one of the parameters - context, in OnPreferenceChangeListener. But when i write: "this", i get an error. I tried to write getContext() instead of this, but it's doesn't work too. Tell me, please, what i can do?

```
public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        final ListPreference lp = (ListPreference) findPreference("background");
        lp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                String s = String.valueOf(newValue);

                  /*error*/
                    DatabaseHelper.updItem(this, s, "my_appearance", "backgroundPatters", 1);

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `MyPreferenceFragment.this`

Comment: Well, what kind of error do you get? Does that hint at something?

Comment: When `onPreferenceChange()` method is executed `this` is a reference to the object the method belongs to. In your case it is object created by `new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener()`.

Comment: Bare `this` always refers to the object in whose method it appears.  In your code, that's an instance of `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener`, which is unlikely to be the object you want to pass to `DatabaseHelper.updItem`.

Comment: luk2302 -  Change 1s parameter of method 'updItem' from 'Context' to 'MyPreferenceFragment'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `this` inside `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` and `this` is a reference to `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` itself in that scope, not the `MyPreferenceFragment`. If you want to pass a reference to `MyPreferenceFragment` then modify your code like this:

```
DatabaseHelper.updItem(MyPreferenceFragment.this, s, "my_appearance", "backgroundPatters", 1);
```

You can read more about `this` here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

**EDIT:** if `DatabaseHelper.updItem` requires `Context` then you can use `getActivity()` or `getContext()` to get `Context` and pass it to `DatabaseHelper.updItem`. something like this:

```
DatabaseHelper.updItem(getContext(), s, "my_appearance", "backgroundPatters", 1);
```

Comment: It's no work. I get again the same error - Change 1st parameter of method 'updItem' from 'Context' to 'MyPreferenceFragment'